# Create a login procedure that prints out if the password or login is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure that when I type an incorrect password or a username it prints out that it is not correct.

So far this is what I have. I think I understand why it isn't working but can't figure out how to validate the @parameters with the login and password.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE login
(
  @login VARCHAR(25),
  @passwrd VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ID_work
    FROM dbo.work 
    WHERE login = @login
        AND password = @passwrd

    IF @login != (SELECT login FROM dbo.work)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'incorrect'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @passwrd != (SELECT password FROM dbo.work)
            PRINT 'incorrect'
    END

END
```

Comment: This looks like you are storing plain text passwords; an extremely concerning and fatal security issue for both you and your users.

Comment: I am quite sure that `IF @login != (SELECT ...)` will fail when there is more than one user stored in that table

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE login
    (@login VARCHAR(25),
     @passwrd VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM dbo.Work
                   WHERE login = @login AND password = @passwrd)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'incorrect'
    END
END
```

Just use `IF NOT EXISTS()` to check if a row with the conditions specified exists; if not, then do a `PRINT 'incorrect'` ....

**WORD OF WARNING**: it appears as if you're storing the password **in clear text** - that's a ***HUGE*** no-no in terms of securing your system. ***DO NOT DO THAT!!!***

Comment: Right, so something like `WHERE login = @login AND  password =  hashbytes('sha2_512',@passwrd)`